# Can you put a stacked bar chart in a tabulator table?

Tags: tabulator

I'm wondering whether you can make turn a progress bar into a stacked horizontal bar chart in tabulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in formatter with this functionality, but it is really simple to add your own [Custom Formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/format#format-custom) to add any type of formatting that you like:

```js
{title:"Name", field:"name", formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
    //cell - the cell component
    //formatterParams - parameters set for the column
    //onRendered - function to call when the formatter has been rendered

    return "Mr" + cell.getValue(); //return the contents of the cell;
}}
```